# Scaling a dendrogram plot in R

Tags: r, height, cut, dendrogram

I want to plot a dendrogram produced by average linkage clustering. The pairwise distances between the objects are all between `0.90` and `1.0`. The result is a tree where you can barely see the height differences. Is there a way to zoom in or scale, such that the differences that do exist take the full height of the plot?

`literature.csv`:

```
file,./doyle_the_adventures_of_sherlock_holmes.txt,./doyle_the_hound_of_the_baskervilles.txt,./fitzgerald_the_beautiful_and_the_damned.txt,./fitzgerald_this_side_of_paradise.txt,./lawrence_sons_and_lovers.txt,./lawrence_the_white_peacock.txt
./doyle_the_adventures_of_sherlock_holmes.txt,0.0007791468073787889,,,,,
./doyle_the_hound_of_the_baskervilles.txt,0.9156855685890994,0.0009740377963077595,,,,
./fitzgerald_the_beautiful_and_the_damned.txt,0.9359979946307857,0.9458024711323867,0.0006671087104182165,,,
./fitzgerald_this_side_of_paradise.txt,0.9248203932273336,0.9283132318706644,0.924584371057994,0.0007603851058105121,,
./lawrence_sons_and_lovers.txt,0.9448158441623475,0.9537187067420674,0.9361454789983296,0.9439788534658211,0.0006760309471944716,
./lawrence_the_white_peacock.txt,0.9340464226303858,0.9441049465183027,0.9315142154801566,0.9353349824600719,0.9286554853294131,0.0006852207789969058
```

R code:

```
library(ape) # for as.phylo function

distances <- "distance_matrices/literature.csv"

distance_matrix <- as.dist( as.matrix( read.csv(distances, row.names=1 ) ) )
clustering <- hclust(distance_matrix, method="average" )

pdf("plots/literature-average.pdf")
plot( as.phylo(clustering) )
dev.off()
```

The result:

[image: literature clustered with average linkage]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (e.g. including your `plot` command and the `dput` of your clustering object): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Done. Sorry for lack of effort.

Comment: A dirty solution could be to rescale the height attributes of the dendrogram: `par(mar = c(2, 2, 2, 20)); plot(dendrapply(as.dendrogram(clustering), function(x) { attr(x, "height") <- attr(x, "height")^32; x  }) , horiz = TRUE, axes = F)`.